# Aid for logical puzzle

Tags: logic, puzzle

I am looking for some help to solve this logical puzzle. The problem I am asked to solve is:

"You’re a famous detective and you’re trying to solve a second murder. You know that the murderer was one of exactly 6 suspects. Among the suspects, one was actually a witness of the crime, but you don’t know who this is. The witness is afraid of the murderer and will not say anything if the murderer will be able to hear it. What you can do is repeatedly select a group of people to go to a separate room. There you can ask them if anyone knows who the murderer is. If the witness is in the room and the murderer is not, they will speak up. You could take all 6 people aside one-by-one, but that will take a long time. How small of a number of groups can you take aside to guarantee that the witness speaks up?"

After studying the proposed solutions from the community, the general agreement was: one needs 4 groups.
I have found a 3 groups solution.

Let’s call N1, N2, N3, N4 the suspects who don’t know who the murderer is, and W and M the witness and the murderer.

We start by splitting the suspects into two groups of three.

First step:

N1  N2  N3      N4  M   W

Second step:
N4  N2  N3      N1  M   W

Nobody speaks up, but we know that N1 is neither the witness nor the murderer.

Third step:
N4  M   N3      N1  N2  W

Now witness and murderer are separated and can be identified.

Comment: What is the relevance of the fact that it is a second murder?

Comment: The rules aren't clear.  Suppose you just ask all six together if they know who the killer is?  By the same logic you gave, you should get two No responses, one from the murderer and one from the witness, right?  Seems useful.  But...why would the murderer say No?  Wouldn't it be smarter to say nothing or "I don't know" just like everyone else?

Comment: And having identified the witness/murderer, how can you hope to finish?  Isolating each of them, they will both, presumably, name the other as the killer.  One is the killer, the other is lying.  How can you distinguish?

Comment: If both say 'no' (case 2), you know that one is lying because there can only be one witness that can be sure of what he/she saw. Another problem is that it's not safe for the witness to answer 'no' when together with the murderer.  If the witness does not say 'I do not know', the murderer then knows the other is lying and must be the witness.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity, as it stands, the rules simply aren't clear.  As a general matter, if the killer knows who the witness is, they can turn the tables simply by acting as if they were the witness, and the real witness was the killer.  I don't see how one could hope to discern which was which in that case.

Comment: Case 1 is not so easy : there will be two groups (Witness,A) & (Murderer,B) with Similar Answers.

Comment: I assume it is Second Murder , because it is Second Puzzle , @JoséCarlosSantos , though we might joke that Second Murder indicates Serial Killer , hence Witness will not want to be the third victim.

Comment: @ Jose Carlos Santos
Agree, I have no idea why it matters that it is a second murder.
@ Lulu and @ Jeroen
I agree with you. My solution is weak. What if the murderer and the witness both answer: " I don't know"

Answer (score 2):

This is the Fano Plane:

[image]

There are 7 points and 7 lines.  Every point is connected to every other point by exactly one line.  Each line has 3 points on it.

You only have 6 suspects, so you can throw away one point, and the lines through that point.

This will leave 4 lines.  Interrogate the group on each line.  This will mean that each witness is interrogated twice, but there will be different people in the room each time.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I have found a three groups solution. What do you think about it?
Let’s call N1, N2, N3, N4 the suspects who don’t know who the murderer is, and W and M the witness and the murderer.

We start by splitting the suspects into two groups of three.

First step:

N1 N2 N3  N4 M W

Second step:
N4 N2 N3  N1 M W

Nobody speaks up, but we know that N1 is neither the witness nor the murderer.

Third step:
N4 M N3  N1 N2 W

Now witness and murderer are separated and can be identified.

Comment: @Shaktyai I can’t follow your strategy.  It looks like your are interviewing all six candidates in the same room all three times.

Answer (score 2):

To show that 3 groups is not sufficient:

- We want to identify the (witness, murderer) ordered pair.
- There are $ 6 \times 5 = 30 $ pairs to check.
- Each grouping allows us to say that (person in group, person not in group) is NOT the pairing.
- Each grouping allows us to check at most $  x(6-x) \leq 9 $ pairs.
- Hence, to check all 30 pairs, we need at least $ \lceil \frac{30}{9} \rceil = 4$  groups.
- User317176 provided such an example of 4 groups, namely checking $EGB, CGF, EDC, BDF$ (we drop point A)

Comment: Thank you. It is very useful and clear.

Comment: I have found a 3 groups solution. What do you think about it?
Let’s call N1, N2, N3, N4 the suspects who don’t know who the murderer is, and W and M the witness and the murderer.

We start by splitting the suspects into two groups of three.

First step:

N1 N2 N3  N4 M W

Second step:
N4 N2 N3  N1 M W

Nobody speaks up, but we know that N1 is neither the witness nor the murderer.

Third step:
N4 M N3  N1 N2 W

Now witness and murderer are separated and can be identified.

Comment: @Shaktyai I have no idea what you're saying. For the first step, what is the group that you're taking into the room?